# open the webpage from IE Mode tab to edge tab

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm accessing a webpage in the edge browser in IE Mode and if I open any link from that page its also opened in IE mode instead of normal edge mode. How to open the link in normal mode instead of IE mode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you may be able to solve this problem by configuring IE mode site list via group policy. But the precondition is that the links you mentioned are not in the same domain as the source page.

You can refer [this offical doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies)
to configure IE mode site list via group policy, which mainly focus on the first two steps:

1. [Configure Internet Explorer integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-internet-explorer-integration)
2. [Redirect sites from IE to Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#redirect-sites-from-microsoft-edge-to-ie-mode)

If you configurethe Internet Explorer mode pages in browser settings, or you access pages via the `Reload tab in IE mode` feature, you can switch to Edge via the banner on the page.

Comment: I'm accessing site A from in the edge browser using IE Mode.  Site A has link for Site B  and when I click the link site B also opening in IE Mode but I need it to be opened in normal edge mode

Comment: As I ready mentioned, it depends on whether the links are the same domain as the source page. In this case, it will be displayed as IE mode by default, which is by design. If they are in the same domain, it is not recommend that you configure via group policy and you will need to switch to Edge manually.